# Is there a way to replicate the SPSS CHAID algorithm in R?

Tags: r, tree, classification, spss, rpart

I am trying to replicate the output obtained in SPSS doing it in R but I do not get the same results. I used the following libraries to help me, but I didn't get the same results as SPSS:

```r
  library ("rpart")
  library ("readr")
  library ("caTools")
  library ("dplyr")
  library ("party")
  library ("party kit")
  library ("rpart.plot")
```

Does anyone know how I could do it? From my research I discovered that at one point there was a library called "CHAID" but now it is no longer available.

Comment: Does `library ("party kit")` actually work for you? I thought R package names could not contain spaces (ref: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file).

Comment: Sorry, it is library ("partykit")

Comment: Try `install.packages("CHAID", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")`.

Comment: It doesn´t work to me.